# Dynamic rendering of message with javascript - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display a message to the user if a screen size is a certain size small. I have a working script for this right now but but I want it to be dynamic not just on page load. Does anybody know how I can achieve this? Here is my current script that uses page load.

```
$(document).load "[data-action='alert']", (event) =>
  if $(window).width() < 768
    alert 'Less than 768'
  else
    alert 'More than 768'
```

That is not finished obviously, but how can I have it toggle the alert message if a person goes back and forth from that size?

Comment: I'm no rails dev, but if we're talking jQuery and running logic on load and on breakpoint change...https://jsfiddle.net/91cx6mm0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use responsive design instead of javascript. It's great for exactly this sort of thing. There are loads of articles and tutorials on responsive design. A quick Google will get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use the resize method

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if $(window).width() < 768
    alert 'Less than 768'
  else
    alert 'More than 768'
});
```